# Cors error in console but returns correct data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, axios, cors

I have a backend in spring boot 3.1 with the login in spring-security 6.1 and when I make the login call, it returns the token but in the console it returns a cors error, although with the code 200

I show you my classes:

> CorsConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

> SpringSecurityConfig Class

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
         http
                 .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                 .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                 .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()))
                 .addFilter(new JwtValidationFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()))
                 .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) -> authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login")
                         .permitAll()
                         .anyRequest()
                         .authenticated()
                 );

         return http.build();
    }
```

> SucessfulAuthentication method

```
  @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String username = ((User)authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();

       Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles =  authResult.getAuthorities();
       //boolean isAdmin = roles.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.getAuthority().equals((ROLE_ADMIN)));
       Claims claims = Jwts.claims();
       claims.put("authorities", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(roles));
       //claims.put("isAdmin", isAdmin);

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(username)
                .signWith(SECRET_KEY)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 36000000))// Tiempo para expiracion del token 10h( hora actual + 1 hora) 3600000 = 1hora
                .compact();

        response.addHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, PREFIX_TOKEN + token);

        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("token", token);
        body.put("message", String.format("Hola %s, has iniciado sesion con exito", username));
        body.put("username", username);
        response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body));
        response.setStatus(200);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
    }
```

> Axios call

```
var data = {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
      
            const response = await axios({
                method: "post",
                url: `${urlLogin}`,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
            })
```

> And Error message in console

[image]

[image]

I only receive the token in the response header, but not the body that I indicate in the sucessfulAuthentication method. From postman I have no problem, it works correctly

[image]

I hope I have explained myself well. I will be attending any answer / question. Thank you so much

Comment: I just noticed - in `Content-Length` it shows 324. So, the response body is there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length. Content-Length does not include size of the header, it is only the body. So, body is there.

Comment: Log the response, and put try-catch.  Expand the `POST ... net:ERR_FAILED 200` and check the full error details with stack-trace.  Check what is on that specific line in the stack-trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it with this configuration in the SimpleCorsFilter Class

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).